# Elements going outside of grid layout

Tags: css

The form has a fixed width of 300px with a grid layout. I have made it two columns by

`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` , and I have also tried `grid-template-columns: auto auto` , but the elements are still going outside of the form.

How to make the elements auto-adjust their width to suit the form width?

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
  <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1fr` means `minmax(auto, 1fr)` which is a well-known concern [here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1777). In your context, `auto` is not obvious, and that causes unexpected widths for your input fields.

To fix it, you should set `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));` instead.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
  <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the overflow of any child elements to a value other than the default of visible.

```css
form input {
overflow: hidden; // New
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  gap: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
  <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```